# ReactJS: How to implement react-cookie properly in an action?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies

I have read articles that saving the token in `localstorage` is dangerous to XSS attack. So I have decided to store my tokens in cookies. And I am using [react-cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cookie). I saw the examples and I am trying to do it but my `auth.js` consists of `const` and is not a class, so I do not know how to use the `withCookies()` with it, this is my `auth.js` where I want to store the token to the cookies:

```
import {
  LOGIN,
  LOGIN_SUCCESS,
  LOGIN_FAILED,

  GET_USER_DATA,
  GET_USER_DATA_SUCCESS,
  GET_USER_DATA_FAILED,

  LOGOUT,
  LOGOUT_SUCCESS,
  LOGOUT_FAILED,
} from './types'

import axios from 'axios'
var api = require ('./../api.js');


export const login = (email, pass) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({
            type: LOGIN
        })
        var url = api.logInApi
        axios.post(url, {
              email: email,
              password: pass
            })
            .then(res => {
                dispatch({
                    type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
                    payload: res.data
                })
                localStorage.setItem('token', res.data.token)
                dispatch(getUserData())
            })
            .catch(err => dispatch({
                type: LOGIN_FAILED,
                payload: err
            }))
    }
}



export const getUserData = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({
            type: GET_USER_DATA
        })
        var url = api.getUserDataApi
        axios.post(url, {}, {headers: {
                "Authorization": `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}` 
              }})
            .then(res => {
                dispatch({
                    type: GET_USER_DATA_SUCCESS,
                    payload: res.data
                })
            })
            .catch(err => dispatch({
                type: GET_USER_DATA_FAILED,
                payload: err
            }))
    }
}


export const logout = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({
            type: LOGOUT
        })
        var url = api.logoutApi
        axios.post(url, {}, {headers: {
                "Authorization": `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}` 
              }})
            .then(res => {
                window.location.replace("")
                dispatch({
                    type: LOGOUT_SUCCESS,
                    payload: res.data
                })
            })
            .catch(err => dispatch({
                type: LOGOUT_FAILED,
                payload: err
            }))
    }
}
```

Now, I tried doing this and of course it doesn't work:

```
import {
  LOGIN,
  LOGIN_SUCCESS,
  LOGIN_FAILED,

  GET_USER_DATA,
  GET_USER_DATA_SUCCESS,
  GET_USER_DATA_FAILED,

  LOGOUT,
  LOGOUT_SUCCESS,
  LOGOUT_FAILED,
} from './types'

import axios from 'axios'
import { withCookies, Cookies } from 'react-cookie'; <<added this
var api = require ('./../api.js');

const login  = (email, pass) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({
            type: LOGIN
        })
        const { cookies } = props; <<added this
        var url = api.logInApi
        axios.post(url, {
              email: email,
              password: pass
            })
            .then(res => {
                dispatch({
                    type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
                    payload: res.data
                })
                cookies.set('token', res.data.token, { path: '/' }); <<added this
                dispatch(getUserData())
            })
            .catch(err => dispatch({
                type: LOGIN_FAILED,
                payload: err
            }))
    }
}
export default withCookies(login) <<added this(wrong)



const getUserData = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({
            type: GET_USER_DATA
        })
        const { cookies } = props; <<added this
        var token = cookies.get('token'); <<added this
        var url = api.getUserDataApi
        axios.post(url, {}, {headers: {
                "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}` <<added this(this is where I wanna get the cookie)
              }})
            .then(res => {
                dispatch({
                    type: GET_USER_DATA_SUCCESS,
                    payload: res.data
                })
            })
            .catch(err => dispatch({
                type: GET_USER_DATA_FAILED,
                payload: err
            }))
    }
}
export default withCookies(getUserData) <<added this(wrong)


const logout = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({
            type: LOGOUT
        })
        const { cookies } = props;
        var token = cookies.get('token');
        var url = api.logoutApi
        axios.post(url, {}, {headers: {
            "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}` <<added this
              }})
            .then(res => {
                window.location.replace("")
                dispatch({
                    type: LOGOUT_SUCCESS,
                    payload: res.data
                })
            })
            .catch(err => dispatch({
                type: LOGOUT_FAILED,
                payload: err
            }))
    }
}
export default withCookies(logout) <<added this(wrong)
```

this one is wrong because there should only be one export default. But I don't know how to implement withCookies to const and there are also these ones that are included in the example and I don't know if I need them or where do I put them:

```
  static propTypes = {
    cookies: instanceOf(Cookies).isRequired
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const { cookies } = props;
    this.state = {
      name: cookies.get('name') || 'Ben'
    };
  }
```

and also, another question is that, I can access my cookies anywhere in my project right? just like how `localstorage` is accessible to my project?

I hope someone can help me and I am a newbie to this. I have never used cookies before so thank you for your consideration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally would rather using [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) to write/read cookies.

It has a very basic API:

```
Cookie.set('cookie_name', 'value') // will set "cookie_name" to "value"
Cookie.get('cookie_name') // will return "value"
```

Which means:

```
const login  = (email, pass, cookie) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({
            type: LOGIN
        })
        var url = api.logInApi
        axios.post(url, {
              email: email,
              password: pass
            })
            .then(res => {
                dispatch({
                    type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
                    payload: res.data
                })
                cookies.set('token', res.data.token);
                dispatch(getUserData())
            })
            .catch(err => dispatch({
                type: LOGIN_FAILED,
                payload: err
            }))
    }
}
```

Passing to the `login` funuction `js-cookie`'s Cookie in the 3rd argument.

Now, you can still use the same `react-cookie` package to read the cookie values (I believe there shouldn't be any conflicts). Or you can replace it with `js-cookie`. To do that, however, you will have to pass the `Cookie` object to props. I probably would do that using `mapStateToProps` if you're using `Redux` or just by simply passing it through `JSX`

Comment: I will take a look at `js-cookie`. I'll get back to you in a minute :)

Comment: I believe it's `Cookies.get` and `Cookies.set`